# Should a field in a Json object always have the same type?

Tags: json

I'm confused about Json. My question is: "Does the Json standard enforce that a field is always represented in the same way?". For example, from an API I access from an Android app, I get

```
"user" : {
  ...
    "avatar": {
      "url": null,
      "normal": {
        "url": null
      },
      "mobile": {
        "url": null
      },
      "retina": {
        "url": null
      }
    },
  ...
}
```

one time, and

```
"user" : {
  ...
    "avatar": "https://......0914.jpg",
  ...
}
```

another time. GSON or Jackson json parsers don't like that, and I'd have to write a converter to cope with it.

Can I tell the maintainer of the API to fix the API, or is this valid Json and my app should deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a serialization format. No more than that. As long as the object is in a valid JSON format, then you can be receiving whatever.

You could be receiving on one request:

```
"user" : {
    "avatar": "https://......0914.jpg"
}
```

And then on the next request

```
"foo" : {
    "bar": "baz"
}
```

And it'd still be valid **JSON**

The API you are using (the one that serializes the objects) is the one supposed to give you consistent results to the same functions (or at least, document the different types of possible results).

This goes not only to JSON, but to any serialization format: if you get inconsistent results from the same API (and those are not documented), it does not matter whether you are receving JSON, XML, binary, plain text, or whatnot.

So yes, if you are receiving a different object format for the same request, and that's not documented, the API is inconsistent and you should contact the API developer and get them to either fix it, or document it.